# Accessing an invisible element in html source code using beautiful soup python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I am trying to **scrape** all the links of the episode buttons (EP 212,211,210,...) on this page https://gogoanime.pe/category/boruto-naruto-next-generations using beautiful soup 4 and python 3. This is the code I am using to retrieve the source code of the webpage:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests as rq

webpage=rq.get('https://gogoanime.pe/category/boruto-naruto-next-generations').text
SourceCode=BeautifulSoup(webpage,'html.parser')
print(SourceCode.prettify())
```

The problem is that the source code I get using this python code is different from the source code that I viewed using the 'inspect element' option on my browser.

For one, in my browser I have seen that there is a tag:

```html
<div id="load_ep"> <ul id="episode_related">
```

with the parent:

```html
<div class="anime_video_body" style="padding: 0 20px 20px 20px;">
```

that contains all the **episode links that I want**. However I cannot see this element in the output of my python code and therefore  am not able to access these.

I want to have access to the original code using beautiful soup inorder to acquire all the links, please teach me how I can do this.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: May be that page is being loaded by Javascript. Use selenium.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.3"
}

url = 'https://gogoanime.pe/category/boruto-naruto-next-generations '

# keep simple and download from https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads (match version of Chrome installed)
# put file in same folder as the script
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
uls = soup.find_all("ul",id="episode_related")

for element in uls:
    for link in element.find_all('a'):
        print(element.find('a').text, link['href'])
```

**Output:**

```
EP 212
SUB
  /boruto-naruto-next-generations-episode-212
EP 212
SUB
  /boruto-naruto-next-generations-episode-211
EP 212......
```

Comment: Thank you very much for taking your time to answer, selenium is what worked for me since it was able to retrieve all the links in the source code

Answer (score 1):

The html for those links is generated by JavaScript running in the browser. Specifically, it is the result of the `loadListEpisode` function detailed in the JS file called:`https://cdn.gogocdn.net/files/gogo/js/main.js?v=5.1`.

In the function definition the request url, for the html containing the links, is given as:

```
url: base_url_cdn_api + 'ajax/load-list-episode?ep_start=' + ep_start + '&ep_end=' + ep_end + '&id=' + id + '&default_ep=' + default_ep + '&alias=' + alias
```

You can dynamically construct this yourself, using the page html you have, then parse out the links from the response to the request to that endpoint:

```
import requests, re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

with requests.Session() as s:
    r = s.get('https://gogoanime.pe/category/boruto-naruto-next-generations')
    soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
    ep =  soup.select_one('.active[ep_start]')
    ep_start = ep['ep_start']
    ep_end = ep['ep_end']
    movie_id = soup.select_one('#movie_id')['value']
    alias = soup.select_one('#alias_anime')['value']
    base_url_cdn_api = re.search(r"base_url_cdn_api = '(.*?)'", r.text).group(1)
    default_ep = soup.select_one('#default_ep')['value']
    api_url = f'{base_url_cdn_api}ajax/load-list-episode?ep_start={ep_start}&ep_end= \
                {ep_end}&id={movie_id}&default_ep={default_ep}&alias={alias}'
    r = s.get(api_url)
    soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
    links = ['https://gogoanime.pe' + i['href'].strip() for i in soup.select('a')]
print(links)
```

Comment: thank you very much for taking your time to answer me, I am a beginner and therefore unfamiliar with some of the beautiful soup functions, I solved the problem using selenium but I still grateful you took your time to help me

Comment: you are most welcome.